# Read the first three strings of a line into individual arrays, then read the rest of the line into a fourth string in C?

Tags: c, assembly, scanf, fgets

I'm writing the first pass of an assembler in C for an assignment and need to read in lines of a text file with assembly code, and store the label, opcode, and operand, as well as any comments in the line after the first three strings. I initially used

`fscanf(fileptr1,"%s\t%s\t%s",label,opcode,operand);`

for a file without comments, but sscanf wouldn't work to put the rest of the line into a single char array. It seems like I would use `fgets`, but how would I separate that into the first three strings separated by whitespace, followed by the rest of the line until the newline character?

For reference, the lines follow this formatting:

```
LABEL   OPCODE  OPERAND     COMMENTS IN MULTIPLE STRINGS
```

I would want the label, opcode, and operand in individual strings, as I have right now, and then a separate string for the entirety of the rest of the line. A few lines from the assembly code for reference:

```
COPY    START   1000        COPY FILE FROM INPUT TO OUTPUT
FIRST   STL     RETADR      SAVE RETURN ADDRESS
CLOOP   JSUB    RDREC       READ INPUT RECORD
        LDA     LENGTH      TEST FOR EOF (LENGTH = 0)
        COMP    ZERO
        JEQ     ENDFIL      EXIT IF EOF FOUND
        JSUB    WRREC       WRITE OUTPUT RECORD
J       CLOOP   LOOP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: read the line with `fgets()`

```
char buffer[256];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer,fileptr1) {
```

---

> how would I separate that into the first three strings separated by whitespace, ...

This is an incorrect assessment of the problem.  The 3 "strings" are not separated by whitespace in the case of `"        LDA     LENGTH      TEST FOR EOF (LENGTH = 0)"` for the first "string"  or `label` is empty.

Instead code needs to look for missing fields.

Step 2: There are numerous approaches:  Below is a try-it-1-of-2-ways depending on if leading character  is a white-space.  Test if scanning succeeded by testing `n`

```
    char label[8];
    char opcode[8];
    char operand[12];
    char comment[sizeof buffer];  // big enough to handle the rest of the line
    label[0] = '\0';
    opcode[0] = '\0';
    operand[0] = '\0';
    comment[0] = '\0';

    int n = 0;  
    if (isspace((unsigned char) buffer[0])) {
      //                      vv--------- Save offset of scan if we got that far
      sscanf(buffer, "%7s%11s %n" , opcode, operand, &n); 
    } else {
      sscanf(buffer, "%7s%7s%11s %n" , label, opcode, operand, &n); 
    }
    if (n == 0) {
      // Handle bad input with TBD code
      continue;
    }
    // look for comment starting at `n`
    if (buffer[n]) {
      // scan in comment  
      sscanf(buffer + n, "%[^\n]" , comment); 
    }

    // do something with input
    printf("<%s> <%s> <%s> <%s>\n", label,opcode,operand,comment);
}
```

---

Code could test for a "too long" a `label,opcode,operand`.  Example:

```
    // Assume max length of opcode == 7
    char opcode[7 + 1 + 1];  // +1 for extra, +1 for null character
    ...
    sscanf(..., "...%8s...", .... opcode ...);
    if (opcode[7 + 1]) Handle_TooLoong();
```

Comment: I appreciate the correction/clarification and attention to the white spaces. Just needed to fix the `fgets()` in the `while()` condition to use `buffer` instead of `fileptr1` and this works! Thank you!

Comment: @TivonMohammed Code amended.

Answer (score 0):

Define the specific delimiter for each field

```
fscanf( fileptr1, "%[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\n]", label, opcode, operand, comment ) ;
```

You should perhaps add field width specifiers and check the return value, to check for errors and overruns but that is a different question.

But there are other means.  For example you could `fgets()` the whole line into one array, then split it up using `strtok()` using `\t` as the delimiter.

```
char line[1024] = {0} ;

fgets( line, sizeof(line), fileptr1 ) ;

char* label = strtok( line, "\t" ) ;
char* opcode = label != 0 ? strtok( 0, "\t" ) : 0 ;
char* operand = opcode != 0 ? strtok( 0, "\t" ) : 0 ;
char* comment = operand != 0 ? strtok( 0, "\n" ) : 0 ;
```

Comment: For the last `strtok()`, would I use `\n` as the delimiter, since I want the remainder of the line to be stored in comment?

Comment: Also, I had some issues integrating this solution into my code. Removing the declarations, since I already declared the strings as arrays previously, caused issues with type mismatches between `char*` and `char[]`. Not sure why this was the case, since I thought that arrays were treated as pointers in cases like this. Tried a few different combinations with leaving those declarations also caused similar problems in other parts of the code. I'm quite new to C, and most of my knowledge as a student is from C++, so maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: @TivonMohammed : The delimiter on the last strtok makes little difference unless the comment contains tabs.  fgets strips the newline in any case; strtok will terminate on nul.

Comment: @TivonMohammed : In the alternative solution, the data types do need to change.  That is why I included the declarations in the fragment.  It is no different in C++; it is only that in C++ the library allows other (better) options. But that is about the library, not the language itself.